# Problems importing imblearn python package on ipython notebook

Tags: python, python-2.7, powershell, jupyter-notebook, imblearn

I installed https://github.com/glemaitre/imbalanced-learn on windows powershell using `pip install`, `conda` and `github`. But when I'm on iPython notebook and I tried to import the package using:

```
from unbalanced_dataset import UnderSampler, OverSampler, SMOTE
```

I get the error:

---

```
ImportError  Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-9-ad6fd7440a05> in <module>()
----> 1 from imbalanced_learn import UnderSampler, OverSampler, SMOTE

ImportError: No module named imbalanced_learn
```

New to using windows for Python, do I have to install the package in some folder?

Comment: hi, did you ever get this to work, and if so, how? I am trying to follow the instructions that the answers give to know avail.

Answer (score 13):

If it don't work, maybe you need to install "imblearn" package.

Try to install:

- pip: `pip install -U imbalanced-learn`
- anaconda: `conda install -c glemaitre imbalanced-learn`

Then try to import library in your file:

- `from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE`

Comment: hi, I have taken those steps that you suggested and it still does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: The "pip" solution worked in the Jupyter notebook. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
from imblearn import under_sampling, over_sampling
```

In order to import `SMOTE`:

```
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE
```

Or datasets:

```
from imblearn.datasets import ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Type 
!pip install imblearn

in jupyter notebook. this worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

pip3 install imblearn --ignore-installed scikit-learn

just ignore the module causing the version mismatch and proceed with installation. the above command fix the below error.
error:

Collecting scikit-learn>=1.1.0 (from imbalanced-learn->imblearn)
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement scikit-learn>=1.1.0 (from imbalanced-learn->imblearn) (from versions: 0.9, 0.10, 0.11, 0.12, 0.12.1, 0.13, 0.13.1, 0.14, 0.14.1, 0.15.0b1, 0.15.0b2, 0.15.0, 0.15.1, 0.15.2, 0.16b1, 0.16.0, 0.16.1, 0.17b1, 0.17, 0.17.1, 0.18, 0.18.1, 0.18.2, 0.19b2, 0.19.0, 0.19.1, 0.19.2, 0.20rc1, 0.20.0, 0.20.1, 0.20.2, 0.20.3, 0.20.4, 0.21rc2, 0.21.0, 0.21.1, 0.21.2, 0.21.3, 0.22rc2.post1, 0.22rc3, 0.22, 0.22.1, 0.22.2, 0.22.2.post1, 0.23.0rc1, 0.23.0, 0.23.1, 0.23.2, 0.24.dev0, 0.24.0rc1, 0.24.0, 0.24.1, 0.24.2)
No matching distribution found for scikit-learn>=1.1.0 (from imbalanced-learn->imblearn)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

`pip install -U imbalanced-learn` should work, although make sure you've met the dependencies for numpy, scipy and scikit-learn.

[Imbalanced-learn 0.3.0 Install Documentation](http://contrib.scikit-learn.org/imbalanced-learn/stable/install.html)

Answer (score 0):

I've tried all of these solutions and nothing worked, only thing that worked for me is changing the kernel. I'm running Jupyter on Amazon Sagemaker and I changed the kernel from pyhton3 to pytorch36 and it worked just fine. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

What finally worked for me was putting the venv into the notebook according to [Add Virtual Environment to Jupyter Notebook](https://janakiev.com/blog/jupyter-virtual-envs/)

Here's what I did, using commands from the article:

```
$ python3 -m pip install --user ipykernel

# add the virtual environment to Jupyter
$ python3 -m ipykernel install --user --name=venv

# create the virtual env in the working directory
$ python3 -m venv ./venv

# activate the venv
$ source venv/bin/activate

# install the package
(venv) pip install imbalanced-learn

# fire up the notebook
(venv) jupyter notebook
```

Answer (score 0):

#imblearn issue resolve
Same issue I have faced I resolve this issue just doing a small change
You should just capitalize the module "Imblearn"

> !pip3 install Imblearn
> import imblearn