# Jupyter: No module named 'imblearn" after installation

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, imblearn

I installed "imbalanced-learn" (version 0.3.1) on ANACONDA Navigator.
When I ran an example from the imbalanced-learn website using Jupyter (Python 3):

```
from imblearn.datasets import make_imbalance
from imblearn.under_sampling import NearMiss
from imblearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from imblearn.metrics import classification_report_imbalanced
```

I got an message regarding "ModuleNotFoundError".

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'imblearn'

How could I resolve this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[Problems importing imblearn python package on ipython notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40008015/problems-importing-imblearn-python-package-on-ipython-notebook)

according to the answer in the above link:

```bash
    conda install -c glemaitre imbalanced-learn
```

A more official one is this:

```bash
conda install -c conda-forge imbalanced-learn
```

Comment: Here's a more official one now:


`conda install -c conda-forge imbalanced-learn`

Comment: this didn't help me to import imblearn package, what did help me was !pip install imblearn, this is a verified answer and now I am curious to know if this answer helped anybody or not. Please comment if anybody was actually able to solve their proble by this approach. Thank you!

Comment: hi @sareek i'm a conda user, so this worked for me :-)

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me:

```
!pip install imblearn
```

Then, I was able to import `SMOTE` package.

```
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE
```

Answer (score 2):

imbalanced-learn is currently available on the PyPi’s reporitories and you can install it via pip:

```
pip install -U imbalanced-learn
```

The package is release also in Anaconda Cloud platform:

```
conda install -c conda-forge imbalanced-learn
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone encounters this problem on Google Cloud Jupyter notebook instances, using **pip3** to install imblearn made it work for me, after failing with **pip** command:

```
pip3 install imblearn
```

or directly in the notebook:

```
!pip3 install imblearn
```

You should see *imblearn (0.0)* and *imbalanced-learn (4.3)* in your pip list.

NB! Make sure to reload your notebooks (File -> Close and Shutdown), otherwise it might fail to import the library after install.

Answer (score 1):

```
conda install -c conda-forge imbalanced-learn
```

It just worries down the problem

Answer (score 1):

One of the below four commands should work.
Only the 3rd worked for me.

conda install -c conda-forge imbalanced-learn

conda install -c conda-forge/label/gcc7 imbalanced-learn

conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf201901 imbalanced-learn

conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf202003 imbalanced-learn

Answer (score 1):

The below code is the most updated one:

conda update -n base -c defaults conda

from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem and I installed `imblearn` first by typing this command:

```
!pip install imblearn
```

in jupyter notebook and then it is fine

Answer (score 0):

Just check if you antivirus or firewall is blocking the download process. I too had the same issue. This happens when you try to install through Anaconda. During the installation process there occurs a permission error. This is probably due to antivirus blocking the 
 download process.

Answer (score 0):

Open Anaconda Prompt and type in

```
pip install imbalanced-learn --user
```

Answer (score 0):

I am working on Jupyter notebook, this work for me:

```
pip install imblearn
```

Answer (score 0):

I used in this code in my Jupyter Notebook and it works fine.

```
! pip install imbalanced-learn
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

`!pip3 install imblearn --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --user`

This will override SSL certificate requirement and complete the installation.

If after this you still get the error, restart the kernel and run just the import code, not this install command again. That will import imblearn successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to upgrade pip first:

```py
pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

then, and only then, was I able to install imbalanced-learn:

```py
pip3 install imbalanced-learn
```