# Getting error in Python Spyder: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'imblearn.oversampling'

Tags: python, spyder, imblearn

```
 pip install -U imbalanced-learn
 from imblearn import under_sampling, over_sampling
 from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
 from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
 from imblearn.oversampling import SMOTE
```

I am trying to use the above code but its throwing the error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'imblearn.oversampling'

Can anyone help me on this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jupyter: No module named 'imblearn" after installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47606873/jupyter-no-module-named-imblearn-after-installation)