# Why getting an Imblearn import error even after imbalanced-learn installed?

Tags: python, jupyter-lab, imblearn

I have tried my best to find the answer on what is going wrong but without any results. Even though I have imbalanced-learn installed, my jupyter lab notebook returns an error saying that there is no imblearn package. I have tried to install imbalanced-learn in many different ways, including using the latest conda install and pip install versions. However, nothing seems to work. Please help.

[code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkpuE.png)

Comment: Have you looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47606873/jupyter-no-module-named-imblearn-after-installation) stackoverflow question?

Comment: Yes, I did. I have tried to install it with latest anaconda version and with latest pip version. It still returns an error, very frustrating

Comment: Basically, you should check which `pip` was used to install the library. Until you don't identify if you installed it in the system Python or in an environment, it is not easy to tell you what is wrong.